# Time in ValueAnimator twice faster than real (Android)

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to add the timer to my android app. I use ValueAnimator to update info on the screen.
Problem: time in ValueAnimator is twice faster than real.
Here is my code:

```
ValueAnimator timerAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(duration, 0f);
timerAnimator.setDuration(duration * 1000);
timerAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

timerAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        Log.d("debug", "animator time: " + animation.getCurrentPlayTime() + "; real time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
        float timeLeft = (Float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        mTimerBar.setProgress(timeLeft);
        int fullSecondsLeft = (int) timeLeft;
        mTimerText.setText(String.valueOf(fullSecondsLeft));
    }
});
timerAnimator.start();
```

Log output:

```
animator time: 8482; real time: 4249
animator time: 8514; real time: 4266
animator time: 8548; real time: 4282
animator time: 8582; real time: 4299
animator time: 8614; real time: 4316
animator time: 8648; real time: 4332
animator time: 8682; real time: 4349
animator time: 8716; real time: 4366
animator time: 8748; real time: 4382
```

I'm really surprised about that behavior. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Maybe android developper settings to change animation time process mess up timings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set animation speed to x2 in my phone's settings. Because of that, it's absolutely normal behavior.
To the end, now I know that use animations as timers is a bad idea!